# Set input value of form to a value from previous form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, web

I am trying to make a login where the user submits their username in a form, then that username is carried over to another page and saved as a value in the name input field. The saved username on the second page is showing up as `[object HTMLInputElement]`, when it should be the username they entered on the first page.

**index.html (first page)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id ="form" action="results.html" method="get">
    <div class="login-box">
      <div id="error"></div>
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="name" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id ="submit">Sign in</button>
      <button type="reset" name="reset" id = "reset">Reset</button>

    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**results.html (second page)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id = "results"></div>
  <a href="/">Back to Form</a>

  <form id ="form" action="results.html" method="get">
  <div class="login-box">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <div class="textbox">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name">

      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('name').setAttribute('value', document.getElementById('name'))
      </script>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input id = "password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="">
    </div>


    <button type="submit" id ="submit">Sign in</button>
    <button type="reset" name="reset" id = "reset">Reset</button>


  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit for clarity: I'm trying to recreate the login funcionality like [this website's](https://americanheritagecu.org/home) Online Login

Comment: `id` in every HTML tag should be unique even though they locate in different files. You should rename one of your input id

Comment: @NekoMi Say what? What rule is that?

Comment: Because this line is really confusing: `document.getElementById('name').setAttribute('value', document.getElementById('name'))`

Comment: @ChanMT , @NekoMi is right. this project/example was kind of rushed but you can see in my answer that i made it ```username```, thanks!

Comment: @RyM in your answer you are getting the value from query string. Your answer will work equally fine with the input id as "name" instead of  "username" as long as you pass the correct id into getElementById. What I was referring is the statement "id in every HTML tag should be unique even though they locate in different files."

Answer (score 1):

In `results.html` change script:

```
    <div class="textbox">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input id="username" type="text" name="name">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        let name = params.get("name")
        document.getElementById('username').setAttribute('value', name)
      </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd of coarse run a front-end check with HTML/JS to ensure the data doesn't purposely pass through and if it does, the server retrieves a POST. This would contain the username/password fields if this is what you were using inside the form.

The server could optionally redirect on failure sending this data back but importantly enough how this gets done shouldn't be as simple as

login?fail=true&user=testaccount&password=10924909042

This would work but it's a big foul so instead with PHP or your language of choice, you'd render the login page out with the post data inserted into the forms and don't pass it via URL.

Comment: If this is being done without the help of a processor, strictly HTML/JS you'd likely with quick thought be left to the URL passing, and so a processor like PHP/NodeJS/ASP any of those would be required for full on dynamic results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the second page in the script:

`var username = document.querySelector("#name").value`

and wherever you want to put it say:

`document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = username`